# How to turn a list of strings into a list of lists (containing ints)

Tags: python

I want to turn `lst = ['123', '456', '789']` into `lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`.

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = list(lst[i])
```

This produced `lst = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9']]`.

How can I turn those string numbers into integers?

Note: I can't use `map`.

Comment: The code you provided does not work. Please make sure your input is correct.

Comment: There *must* be *plenty* of duplicates among the existing [2,028,197 Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = ['123','456','789']
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = [int(x) for x in lst[i]]
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension approach:

```
lst = ['123', '456', '789']
lst = [[int(i) for i in string_number] for string_number in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
lst = [['123'],['456'],['789']]
ans = []
temp = []

for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        temp = list(j)
        for k in range(len(temp)):
            temp[k] = int(temp[k])
        ans.append(temp)
        
print(ans)
```

```
# output - [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a simple solution for your problem:

```
final_list = []
for i in lst:
    tmp_list = []
    text = str(i[0])
    for c in text:
        tmp_list.append(int(c))
    final_list.append(tmp_list)
```